# Events blocked in portrait mode after scaling body

Tags: javascript, ipad, scaling

I'm writing an application which scales depending on the window size. However, on an iPad1 and iPad3 (and probably on an iPad2) all events are blocked in portrait mode. In landscape mode everything works perfectly (but the design fits better in portrait mode). On an iPad4 the application works both in portrait and landscape mode.
Anyone has any idea what is going wrong?

```
function setAppSize() {

var $page = $('.page');

var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var pageWidth = $page.width();
var pageHeight = $page.height();

scaleFactor = Math.min(winWidth/pageWidth,winHeight/pageHeight);

$('body').css({'-webkit-transform':  'scale(' + scaleFactor + ',' + scaleFactor + ')'});
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    setAppSize();
});

$(window).bind('orientationchange',function() {
    setAppSize();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that all your click handlers etc stop responding?

Comment: Yes, I can click all I want, but nothing happens while there are several divs with click-handlers.

Comment: Hm. Do things the event handlers still fail if you comment out the `$("body").css(...)` line?

Comment: No, without the -webkit-transform the event handlers work fine (but the application doesn't scale right of course).

Comment: At this point I'd have to see the HTML and JavaScript we're dealing with. Is this site available publically?

Comment: No, unfortunately not and we don't really want it to be yet. I'll try to produce a sample page which has the same problem tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have something to do with JP-Player, an external library I use for playing audio. Disabling this, makes my sampleCode work. I'll look for an other audio-library, any suggestions?

edit: found another library and everything works fine now. Thanks for your time!